# LWC optional chaining "array?.length' in expression causes output of "[object Object]"

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, expressions, proxy

Context: In my LWC, I have an array that may not be defined, and I want to check its length. So I use the optional chaining `arr?.length` to not error if the array is undefined. I also want to default to zero if the array isn't defined, and add one to the whole expression. So the code is:

```
(arr?.length || 0) + 1
```

What do you think this code will do? Well, if I run it verbatim in a console, I get:

```
const arr = [];
(arr?.length || 0) + 1
// outputs 1
```

So far so good. Now let's do a similar experiment in a LWC:

```
export default class component extends LightningElement {
  arr = [];

  get output() {
    return (this.arr?.length || 0) + 1;
  }
}
```

And template:

```
<template>
  output: {output}
</template>
```

Surprisingly, this outputs **`[object Object]1` to the template!**

If I `console.log()` the full expression in the LWC, I also see `[object Object]1`.

Confusingly, if I console.log the variables in the getter method, right click on them and save them as global variables, then run the same expression, the output is `1`.

Why is this behavior happening? Is it related to LWCs hijacking class properties with Proxies?

I threw an error and paused on exceptions in the Chrome inspector to see what the LWC compiled source is. Weirdly it's inlining the string as part of the getter, and not preserving the expression.

[image: showing the string literal "object Object" in the compiled code]

Comment: I tried this in a Aura App with LWC yields the expected output (e.g. 1), both when the array is null/undefined and not. What API version are you using? What browser are you using? What's the context (Aura App, Lightning App Builder, etc)?

Comment: Chrome, API 51, and Service cloud + lightning app page

Comment: Hmm, still nothing, working as expected. Maybe you could build a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) we can copy-paste/deploy?

Comment: This works for me. https://webcomponents.dev/edit/2SZJerXsVR7QZaCI3k8Q If you are populating arr some other way, it could be proxy object. Try forcing it to an array first [...this.arr]?.length

Answer (score 0):

It's actually weird, as it should not work that way.

You could maybe force the boolean evaluation to be a number, and that way it should execute the add operation and not the concatenation. But as the others said, that's not the actual behaviour in any other scenario.

```
return Number((this.arr?.length || 0)) + 1;
```

note: sorry but I'm not able to post comments yet :(